# putting the sidebar over the navigation bar

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

We got this weird wireframe from our project leader which must be done in wordpress. (Notice I'm in college) In the wireframe the sidebar is on top of the navigation bar.

Now our leader recommended to use twenty eleven. But I can't seem to get the sidebar on top of the navigation (Or anything close that)

I have tried to mess around with the styles (changing the positions) but with no luck.

[image]

From : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHXJD.png

Comment: Excuse me for not being able to display the image normally. Not enough reputation..

Comment: May i ask why my question got -1'd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any rules as to what you can or can't use?

It seems like you could use a combination o absolute positioning and z-index. Does that make sense?

Something like this:

```
body{ position: relative;}
#menu{position: absolute; padding-top: 250px; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 100px; width: 200px; z-index: 1;}
```